# angular can't update because of typescript dependencies

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, command-line-interface

Here is my ionic info:

```
Ionic CLI                     : 6.2.1 (C:\Users\Arashsoft\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.0.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.25
@angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.3.25
@angular/cli                  : 9.0.6
```

I want to update `@angular-devkit/build-angular` but get these errors:

1. Firstly, I got these errors after running `ng update @angular/core`:

   > ```
   > Repository is not clean. Please commit or stash any changes before updating.
   > ```
2. Then i tried again using this command:

   ```
   ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --allow-dirty
   ```

   and then got these errors:

   > ```
   > Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires ">=3.1 < 3.6", would install "3.7.5").      
   > × Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
   > Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
   > You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
   >   See "C:\Users\ARASHS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-zWLLPl\angular-errors.log" for further details.
   > ```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ionic [doesn't seem to support Angular 9 yet](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/support#core-dependencies), it'd probably be better to wait until official support arrives.

If you still want to try it Angular has [a dedicated upgrade page](https://update.angular.io/#8.0:9.0l3) where you can follow the procedure. In a nutshell:

- You update `@angular/cli` and `@angular/core` to the latest 8.x.x Version
- You update `@angular/cli` and `@angular/core` to the latest 9.x.x Version, ignoring peer dependency problems with `--force` might be necessary temporarily
- After that you can update the other Angular related dependencies via `ng update`
- Once all your dependencies are up-to-date the error message should go away

As for `1)` your git repo needs to be clean because Angular doesn't want to mess with your local changes, you've probably changed some files, you can see what changed with a git client like [Sourcetree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) or simply by using the command line `git status` which will print what files have changed.

Regarding `2)` I wouldn't recommend using `--allow-dirty`, always try to get a clean git state and then do the upgrade.

If you're new to git I strongly recommend [reading up on the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs)

Hope this helps, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute this:

```
ng update @angular/core@~10 --force
```

Next, update the typescript version, It could be done by this

```
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
```